# How to fix "java.io.InvalidClassExcept local class incompatible" error?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to do a notepad application and I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SLa3EucLI0) and when i'm trying to compile it shows this error

```
System.err: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.example.note.Note; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 2205386845645338430, local class serialVersionUID = -8697044096579308546
```

and the error shows that it is in this function where when you run the app it will show the notes you saved before you existed the app

```
  public static ArrayList<Note> getAllSavedNotes(Context context) {
    ArrayList<Note> notes = new ArrayList<>();

    File filesDir = context.getFilesDir();
    ArrayList<String> noteFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String file : filesDir.list()) {
        if(file.endsWith(FILE_EXTENSION)) {
            noteFiles.add(file);
        }
    }

    FileInputStream fis;
    ObjectInputStream ois;

    for (int i = 0; i < noteFiles.size(); i++) {
        try{
            fis = context.openFileInput(noteFiles.get(i));
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            System.out.println(i);
            notes.add((Note) ois.readObject());
            fis.close();
            ois.close();

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    return notes;
}
```

Can someone help me fix this error?

Comment: You need to have the class doing the serializing use the same version of Note as the deserializing class.  One is using an older version and the other a newer version.

Comment: Can you show the Note class?
Do you have explicit serialVersionUID defined in it?

Comment: @tentacle no i dont have serialVersionUID defined, i was just following a tutorial

Comment: Try to add serialVersionUID. It should be the same for serialized and deserialized classes.
Exception you've provided clearly says that's the issue.

Comment: @tentacle it shows the same error

Comment: Are you sure you've serialized the same version of classes you are trying to read?
If you change just reading side it won't work.